# Is there any way of explaining the Cayley/Beltrami–Klein metric to undergrads?

Tags: undergraduate-education, exercises

How to explain the Cayley-Klein or sometimes called Beltrami–Klein metric concept to find the distance between two points in a hyperbolic space to an audience with no higher education than maybe a second or third-year undergrad? What are a, b, C and what are p, q on quadric Q.

${\displaystyle d(a,b)=C\log {\frac {\left|bp\right|\left|qa\right|}{\left|ap\right|\left|qb\right|}}}$

Furthermore, is there any exercises online in finding distance using the above concept?

Comment: Are the undergraduates B.S. Mathematics students?

Comment: And why would you want to do this?

Comment: As part of a course?  As a one off "talk"?  What is the context.  Both should be possible.  In a course you could actually get them to compute and work with such metrics, while in a "talk" you could probably only convey the flavor of the field.

Comment: You might consider checking out the book by Nam-Hoon Lee: Geometry from Isometries to Special Relativity in the Springer Undergradute Texts in Math for a gentle intro to hyperbolic geom. You will find special cases of the metric in there and the general formula is left as as exercise

Comment: @usr0192 thanks for pointing out this book. Very interesting.

Comment: Do your students have any linear algebra? If this were a course for students who know some linear algebra, I'd introduce the hyperboloid model https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid_model . Then, let $A$ be the matrix which maps $p$ to $q$ and fixes the plane $\text{Span}(p,q)^{\perp}$. The eigenvalues of $A$ are $e^{d(p,q)}$, $e^{-d(p,q)}$, $1$, $1$, ..., $1$ . I think this is the prettiest way to understand the metric, and checking that it matches the above formula in the Beltrami-Klein model is a good exercise.

Comment: By way of analogy, let $p$ and $q$ be points on the unit sphere, and let $A$ be the rotation with $A(p) = q$ fixing $\text{Span}(p,q)^{\perp}$. Let $\theta$ be the spherical distance between $p$ and $q$, then the eigenvalues of $A$ are $e^{i \theta}$, $e^{-i \theta}$, $1$, $1$, ..., $1$.